# Deflate XML for custom SAML integration?

Tags: apex, xml, saml

I need to be able to deflate (or gzip) an XML string for a custom SAML SSO integration.  It does not seem that Apex supports this.  (It does allow you to compress and HttpRequest, however, that does not fit my use case.)

I have found an open source library, Zippex, however that is for working with zip archives.  So this too does not fit my use case.

Other languages/platforms, e.g. Java or C#, provide classes to support compression of strings or xml.

My use case is basically this:

1. Generate SAML AuthNRequest xml.
2. Deflate the xml.
3. Base64 encode the xml.
4. UrlEncode the result, and issue a redirect to the SAML identity provider.

I can do 1, 3, and 4 fairly easily.

How might I accomplish #2, deflating xml with apex and salesforce?

Comment: It seems GZIP does not have enough demand to merit a native salesforce API.
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000hMeOAAU

Comment: Why can't you use out of the box SF Identity features to generate the request?

Comment: This adds a "Sign in with ..." button to the Login page, for business reasons I cannot have additional sign in options appear.

Comment: Your best option other than generating your own request is to use identity provider initiated SSO. If you identity provider doesn't support that, then JavaScript is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

You can find Visualforce code that implements a JavaScript deflate algorithm online as part of the PlantUML integration here: https://github.com/rsoesemann/plantuml4force
It may be a round-about example, but at least it demonstrates using the algorithm you need on the platform. And, note that you can deflate a SOAP or REST request with a Content-Encoding: deflate header.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own deflate algorithm, but there's no out-of-the-box algorithm you can call upon.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while, but this is what I ended up using. Might help!

https://github.com/woojingod/google-apps-sso-sample/blob/master/cs/Google.Apps.SingleSignOn/src/SamlParser.cs